# Babylon.js: rendering order of instances

Tags: javascript, babylonjs, gltf

At the moment I'm trying Babylon.js, because I've only worked with Threejs so far and Babylon.js has been recommended to me several times.

I develop a turn-based strategy game in which the players have game fields made up of individual fields that differ in material (white, black, brown).

Using Threejs I merged the different fields with the same material into one object, to reduce the draw calls to 3. I read in the Babylon.js docs, that it's quite simple to use instances. That's why I implemented the gamefield in this way:

1. Load of the field mesh exported with blender in gltf/glb format. Cloning it 3 times to apply 3 different materials

```js
import { SceneLoader, StandardMaterial, Color3, Vector3 } from 'babylonjs';
import 'babylonjs-loaders';

...

SceneLoader.ImportMesh('', 'models/', 'field.glb, scene, group => {
    group.forEach((mesh, i) => {
        if (mesh.name !== '__root__') {
            let brown = mesh.clone('FIELD_BROWN');
            let brownMaterial = new StandardMaterial("brownField", scene);
            brownMaterial.diffuseColor = new Color3.FromHexString("#824529");
            brown.material = brownMaterial;
            brown.isVisible = false;

            let black = mesh.clone('FIELD_BLACK');
            let blackMaterial = new StandardMaterial("blackField", scene);
            blackMaterial.diffuseColor = new Color3.FromHexString("#3E211B");
            black.material = blackMaterial;
            black.isVisible = false;

            mesh.name = 'FIELD_WHITE';
            let whiteMaterial = new StandardMaterial("whiteField", scene);
            whiteMaterial.diffuseColor = new Color3.FromHexString("#F8DBAF");
            mesh.material = whiteMaterial;
            mesh.isVisible = false;
        } else {
            mesh.isVisible = false;
        }
    });
});
```

2. Build the gamefield in another function

```js
import { Vector3, Color3 } from 'babylonjs';

...

playerField.grid.forEach((cell, i) => {
    let pivot;            

    if (cell.type === BoardCellTypes.BROWN) {
        pivot = this.scene.getMeshByName('FIELD_BROWN');
    } else if (cell.type === BoardCellTypes.BLACK) {
        pivot = this.scene.getMeshByName('FIELD_BLACK');
    } else {
        pivot = this.scene.getMeshByName('FIELD_WHITE');
    }

    let field = pivot.createInstance(cell.row + ':' + cell.col);
    field.position = fieldPosition.add(new Vector3(cell.row * this.fieldSize, 3, cell.col * this.fieldSize));
});
```

The resulting scene looks like this:

[image: Maybe wrong rendering order]

When I resize the window all brown and black fields disappear.

I also see this warning in my console (256 times):

> [.WebGL-0x7fe20b9b3400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElementsInstancedANGLE: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 4

Do I use a wrong concept, or do I have a wrong mental model of how things work using Babylon.js? I think that it could be a problem of the rendering oder, but I'm very confused of the warnings and the disappearing fields. Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by removing the `clone` methods and importing the mesh multiple times:

```js
SceneLoader.ImportMesh('', 'models/', 'field.glb, scene, group => {
    group.forEach((mesh, i) => {
        if (mesh.name !== '__root__') {
            mesh.name = 'FIELD_BROWN';
            let brownMaterial = new StandardMaterial("brownField", scene);
            brownMaterial.diffuseColor = new Color3.FromHexString("#824529");
            mesh.material = brownMaterial;
            mesh.isVisible = false;
        }
});

SceneLoader.ImportMesh('', 'models/', 'field.glb, scene, group => {
    group.forEach((mesh, i) => {
        if (mesh.name !== '__root__') {
            mesh.name = 'FIELD_BLACK';
            let blackMaterial = new StandardMaterial("blackField", scene);
            blackMaterial.diffuseColor = new Color3.FromHexString("#3E211B");
            mesh.material = blackMaterial;
            mesh.isVisible = false;
        }
});

...
```

This worked for me and it removes the warnings and the strange behavior. But I don't understand why. So I'm going to accept the answer which explains me this side effect of cloning using Babylon.js

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that after resizing there is only the last mesh is visible.
Seems that you need to call makeGeometryUnique on the cloned meshes. This method creates a un-shared specific occurence of the geometry for the mesh.

Similar question - https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/creating-instances-of-clones-of-a-mesh/536

Playground link - https://playground.babylonjs.com/#QXZ4KH#3